# Why my kafka tmp folder have almost same size than disk size?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I develop production kafka environment with this formation: 3 ZK server, 3 Kafka brokers and Two kafka connect. I put my tmp file side-by-side with my kafka main folder. And I run it in remote ubuntu environment but not in docker.

When i operate my kafka operation, i experienced error which inform my disk are consumed too much. I check my kafka tmp folder that the size is about almost 2/3 of my disk size, which turn off my kafka cluster.

I have inspect for each kafka log_folder and found this:

1. 25 `connect_offset` from workers no.1 @21MB for each one
2. 25 `connect_offset2` from workers no.2 @21MB for each one
3. 25 `connect_status` from workers no.1 @21MB for each one
4. 25 `connect_status2` from workers no.2 @21MB for each one
5. 50 `__consumer_offset` from both workers @21MB for each one
6. topics offset @21Mb for each one per topics, which I have 2 topics so I have 6 topics offset

The problem is the number of __consumer_offset is consume more disk than the other offset, and my kafka_config cannot handle it. This is the example of my kafka_configuration:

```
broker.id=101
port=
num.partitions=3
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleanup.policy=delete
log.retention.bytes=1073741824
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=60000
message.max.bytes=1073741824
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=7200000
session.time.out.ms=30000
delete.topic.enable=true
```

And for each topics, this is the config:

```
kafka-topics.sh -create --zookeeper ... --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic ... --config cleanup.policy=delete --config retention.ms=86400000 --config min.insync.replicas=2 --config compression.type=gzip
```

And the connect config like this (connect config share identical config except port and offset and status config.):

```
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=3
offset.flush.timeout.ms=300000
connector.client.config.override.policy=All
producer.max.request.size=1073741824
producer.ack=all
producer.enable.idempotence=true
consumer.max.partition.fetch.bytes=1073741824
consumer.auto.offset.reset=latest
consumer.enable.auto.commit=true
consumer.max.poll.interval.ms=5000000
```

It's very obvious that according to several documentation, Kafka doesn't need large disk space (the largest recorded tmp is 36 GB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "@ 21 MB"? Your `log.segment.bytes` is set at 1GB...

---

First, don't use `/tmp` for persistent storage, ever. And don't use `/home` for server data. Always use a separate partition/disk for server data as well as `/var` + `/var/logs`.

Second, you have 2 Connect Clusters. Use the same 3 topics and the same `group.id`, then you have 1 Distribtued Cluster and you save yourself from having 3 extra topics.

Finally,

> the number of __consumer_offset is consume more disk than the other offset

Well, yes. All consumer groups store their offsets there. This will be the largest internal topic, by far, depending on your [`offsets.retention.minutes`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#offsets.retention.minutes)

> Kafka doesn't need large disk space

It doesn't ***when you are getting started*.**

I've seen clusters with tens-hundreds of TB of storage

If you watch Kafka Summit talks from large companies, they are sending GB of events *per second* (ref. Netflix, Spotify, Uber, etc)

---

#### Kafka in Production

1. [Apache](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#prodconfig)
2. [Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html)

Comment: so at first i must not use tmp folder in my machine as persistent storage and put my kafka installation not in home. But how about ```offset.retention.minutes``` ? is it okay to overide it?