# Configure __consumer_offset in kafka_connect to reduce space

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have read that there is a config on brokers to setting how long offset data is retain with `offset.retention.minutes` .My Kafka architecture consist of 3 ZK, 3 Brokers and 2 kafka connect workers. The setting i use comes with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529093/why-my-kafka-tmp-folder-have-almost-same-size-than-disk-size/61532035#61532035). I have set this config to 10 minutes but there's no effect and still i have error cause my disk is full and i supposed that the `__consumer_offset` are the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done about some research about the impact of consumer offset setting. It is not consumer_offset only which contribute to disk space consumption, but also topics retention time. So in my case, i use size and time based retention instead set it only size or time.

Answer (score 0):

**[offsets.retention.minutes](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#offsets.retention.minutes)**

Below statement is from the Kafka documents.

After a consumer group loses **all its consumers** (i.e. becomes empty) its offsets will be kept for this retention period before getting discarded. For standalone consumers (using manual assignment), offsets will be expired after the time of **last commit plus this retention period**.

[In Kafka 2.4.0](https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/2.4.0/RELEASE_NOTES.html) release, an improvement KAFKA-8730 has been added which provides the functionality to manually delete the _consumer_offset ( [KIP-496](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-496%3A+Administrative+API+to+delete+consumer+offsets) )

In the KafkaAdminClient class, the **deleteConsumerGroupOffsets** function is provided for the same. Please go through the following URLs to have detailed information on this.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/7276

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.java

Hope it will be hopefull to you.

Comment: Thank you @rohit-yadav for your response, but in my case I use kafka connect system and i produce message in and out rely from Debezium CDC as source and JDBC sink as consumer to target DB, which i hope there's a config that i can access and tweak to manage my ```consumer_offset``` being not too high. My retention planning per topics is about 1 hour or after 1 GB capacity is meet